# Using a popup div instead of a url with Disqus SSO login link

Tags: php, jquery-ui, disqus

I'm not sure how to better formulate my question, so I'll just descibe my situation : I succesfully installed Disqus and the Single Sign-On API on my site so my users can use their account on my site to comment without the need for additionnal credentials. [Disqus  provide a custom login link](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/236206#sso-login) for users to log in directly from the comments section. The link opens a new window and, after the user has logged in and the window closes, Disqus refreshes the comments.

My problem is that you need to have a new window, which is hard to style to create a seemless experience for the user. I would rather have a Jquery UI popup div, or some other way of having the login process inside the same page. Do you know if such a tweak is possible? If not, could you give me styling hints to improve the popup window so it doesn't stand out too much (centering, removing borders, auto-focus, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't secure for us to allow entering passwords in the same window, and you'll notice that all login options are loaded in a new window (not just SSO). So there's no way to do this specifically.

You don't have to use our SSO login experience, as some sites instead put their login option right above `<div id="disqus_thread"></div>`. If you do that, just make sure you keep the "Logout" link in the configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure how entering the password in the same window is less secure, but you are right that every login option opens a new window, so I guess I'll just stick to that. Thanks!